# Jquery : how to custom a CLICK event?

Tags: jquery, events

I'd like to restrict the jQuery Click Event.

The Problem: if you keydown whatever key... and click with the mouse: click is fired.

For a JS game dev., I'd prefer:

If whatever key is down... and you click: **click is NOT fired**

How to prepare un `$.event.special.click` for a absolutely and strictly "ONLY-mouse" click ?

Answer (score 4):

This can be done simply by using a [semaphore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)), such as a spinning lock.

This is accomplished by incrementing a lock while keydown is pressed. When keyup occurs, set that lock to 0. Inside of your click event, test to see if the lock is 0. If it is not, then do not issue the click action.

```
var SpinningLock = 0;

$('#target').keydown(function() {
  SpinningLock++;
});

$('#target').keyup(function() {
  SpinningLock = 0;
});

$('#target').click(function() {
  if( SpinningLock > 0) return;
  //TODO: implement click action
});
```

Comment: I gave you a plus one, but this is not a semaphore, it is a global flag.

Comment: @Hogan - I always viewed a spinning lock as the most simple version of a semaphore (binary semaphore). However, it is true that this implementation makes use of a global variable ( in the form of a counting flag ) and is not nearly as complex as a true semaphore in a multi threaded environment would be.

Comment: Not really - even a binary semaphore controls access to a resource from multiple threads and is a lock, you have no locking code here and are using a single thread, you simply have a flag.